# font-lock-mode and printing in colour

Tags: font-lock, colors

After making a new buffer, `font-lock-mode` could either be enabled on disabled.  For instance, if I use `(text-mode)` or `(org-mode)` will automatically enable `font-lock-mode`.  However, for `(fundamental-mode)`, `font-lock-mode` is off.

**Solution 1 for colour printing**

For printing in colour, I can enable `font-lock-mode` if it is disabled, then change the colour with `(propertize ... 'font-lock-face ...)`.  Finally, disable `font-lock-mode` as it was originally.

**Solution 2 for colour printing**

Another solution is to test whether `font-lock-mode` in on or off.

If `font-lock-mode` is off, use `(propertize ... 'face ...)`.

If `font-lock-mode` is on, use `(propertize ... 'font-lock-face ...)`.

Then one can apply both properties, so the then colour will work no matter whether `font-lock-mode` is on or not.

Is there any particular solution which is preferable over the other?

Comment: In Solution 2, if `font-lock-mode` is off, what `face are you using in the `propertize`?

Comment: I am doing this `(insert (propertize "G" 'font-lock-face '(:background "#3D3DFF" :foreground "black")))`.

Comment: The question was: what do you do in the *other* case? You say: `If font-lock-mode is off, use (propertize ... 'face ...)` - what face is that?

Comment: It is `(insert (propertize "G" 'face '(:background "#3D3DFF" :foreground "black")))`.

Comment: Sorry - I misunderstood.

Comment: You could add your own property as an alias to `face` in `char-property-alias-alist`. That way it would work both with and without font-lock mode.

Comment: I don't think solution 1 will work. When font-lock mode is disabled, it removes `font-lock-face` as an alias for `face` from the `char-property-alias-alist`, so anything you have inserted will no longer be highlighted.

Comment: This has been made too complicated to comprehend.  I am making a new buffer and want to write coloured text in it.  After I set the buffer to `text-mode` or `org-mode`, `font-lock` is enabled automatically and use `font-lock-face`.  But if I do not set up the mode, I get `fundamental-mode` as the mode of the buffer.  Does it mean that one is not allowed to print in colour when one is in fundamental mode?

Comment: It means that `font-lock-mode` is implemented in a "bad" way. Normally, you should be able to insert text with the `face` attribute. However, when `font-lock-mode` is enabled, it takes over the `face` property but provides an alias property, `font-lock-face`, in case someone would like to bypass font-lock and use coloured text anyway. A better implementation would have left `face` to the user and used `font-lock-face` - but, hey, it's hard to change something that has been around for 20+ years. Anyway, as I said, you can add your own alias property which would always work like `face`.

Comment: It is no excuse for Gnu Developers to do a bad job.  At any rate, can you show me what you have in mind?  My use of faces is very basic.

Comment: What do you mean by `leaving face to the user and used font-lock-face` ? In my use of propertize, I only use `font-lock-face`, and I do not specify an actual face.